# What's the best way to return a sample of data over the a period?

Tags: database, nosql, arangodb, aql

Let's say I have a collection with 3600 documents — one per second for the last hour — and each document has two fields: `timestamp` and `value`.

What is the best (read: most performant) method to select a sample of this data, say, 12 documents, with five minutes between? Or 60 documents, one per minute?

In reality, this collection will have tens of millions of records, and the query will be ran quite often, so performance really is key. With an index on the two fields a query filtering by `timestamp > {one hour ago}` is relatively quick on a collection with 200,000 records.

This post has been succeeded by [Aggregating averages from large datasets for number of steps over period of time in ArangoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72875252/aggregating-averages-from-large-datasets-for-number-of-steps-over-period-of-time).

Comment: What format did you store the timestamps in? Unix Epoch Time? When saving time data in Arango, I prefer to use Unix Epoch Time because then you can put a standard persistent index on the datetime value and you get great performance.

Comment: I'm using millisecond timestamps but easy to switch this out for performance gains. I'll do almost anything for performance gains. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Side note: Analyzing this kind of data, `WINDOW` could be helpful (https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-window.html), e.g. not selecting a value randomly (every Xth documents value), but the `MAX/MIN/AVG` value in the selected window (e.g. a minute span window of 60 documents).

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the tip, that's a great point, being able to select the average for each period would be perfect. I'll give this a go. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to this is:

```sql
LET steps = 24
LET stepsRange = 0..23
LET diff = @end - @start
LET interval = diff / steps

FOR step IN stepsRange
RETURN FIRST(
    LET stepStart = start + (interval * step)
    LET stepEnd = stepStart + interval

    RETURN FIRST(
        FOR f IN filteredObservations
        FILTER f.timestamp >= stepStart AND f.timestamp <= stepEnd
        COLLECT AGGREGATE temperature = AVG(f.temperature)
        RETURN temperature
    )
)
```

For more details, see the answer in my question with superseded this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72886996/1138620

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it like this:

```
FOR doc IN Samples
FILTER doc.timestamp > @start AND doc.timestamp < @end
FILTER FLOOR(doc.timestamp/1000) % 300 == 0
RETURN doc
```

The `timestamp` is assumed to be millisecond based Unix timestamp, like what is returned by the `DATE_NOW()` function.

Where `@start` is the start timestamp of the period, and `@end` is the end of the period.

The above returns the first documents of each 5 minute time slice in the period. If you want one per minute then change the `300` to `60` in the formula. You can also change the `0` to something else if you want not the first document but the one that is X second from the beginning of that time slice.

One thing that can help improve the speed is if you stored the timestamp in second based Unix timestamp, because then the formula could be simpler: `doc.timestamp % 300 == 0` requiring less calculations per documents.

And as mentioned in the comments, use a permanent index on the `timestamp` which will significantly speed up the first filter line.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for this. I'll give it a go and let you know. I was returning an hour of documents and filtering manually, stepping back in time from now to now-1 hour, selecting 1 for each step. I'll see if I can use your query suggestion above, tweaked, to do the same. Great tip on the seconds. I guess `% 300000` would also work in the same way without having to modify timestamps in the data. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Yeah, let me know. Good idea on using the `% 300000` to use less calculations. The only thing is in that case I would modify the condition to be `doc.timestamp % 300000 < 1000` because you probably won't have the timestamp exactly at the .000 second but a bit after that.